# Converting an nvarchar into a custom time format to query upon duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, duration

I am working with a table that has a variety of column types in rather specific and strange formats. Specifically I have a column, 'Total_Time' that measures a duration in the format:
*days:hours:minutes (d:hh:mm)*

**e.g** 200:10:03 represents 200 days, 10 hours and 3 minutes.

I want to be able to run queries against this duration in order to filter upon time durations such as

```
SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[myData] WHERE Total_Time < 0:1:20
```

Ideally this would provide me with a list of entries whose total time duration is less than 1 hour and 20 minutes. I'm not aware of how this is possible in an nvarchar format so I would appreciate any advice on how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance...

Comment: `nvarchar` is text, not time, no matter what that text looks like. If you want to be able to query, sum, modify that data without problems, store it in a suitable type. SQL Server has no duration or interval type though. People often convert durations to the smallest interval eg seconds or minutes, and store that as a number

Comment: The advice would be to normalise your design - you are currently storing separate atomic delimited values in a text column which violates basic 1NF. This design is *always* going to give you performance and querying issues. If you want minutes granularity store an integer representing the duration as minutes, you can then convert that to days, hours and minutes for display.

Comment: Range searches and ordering won't work with such a format anyway. Databases (not just SQL Server) will sort and search such fields using dictionary order, so `0:2:0` will always appear before `0:10:0`. The colon `:` comes after all numbers.  The query `WHERE Total_Time < 0:2:0` would return even `0:23:59`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest converting that value to minutes, and then passing the parametrised value as minutes as well.

If we can *assume* that there will always be a days, hours, and minutes section (so `N'0:0:10'` would be used to represent 10 minutes) you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'200:10:03'))V(Duration)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',V.Duration)))H(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',V.Duration,H.CI+1)))M(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(V.Duration,H.CI-1)),TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.Duration,H.CI+1, M.CI - H.CI-1)),TRY_CONVERT(int, STUFF(V.Duration,1,M.CI,''))))DHM(Days,Hours,Minutes)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES((DHM.Days*60*24) + (DHM.Hours * 60) + DHM.Minutes))D(Minutes)
WHERE D.[Minutes] < 80; --1 hour 20 minutes = 80 minutes
```

If you can, then ideally you should be fixing your design and just storing the value as a *consumable* value (like an `int` representing the number of minutes), or *at least* adding a computed column (likely `PERSISTED` and indexed appropriately) so that you can just reference that.

If you're on SQL Server 2022+, you could do something like this, which is less "awful" to look at:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'200:10:03'))V(Duration)
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(CASE SS.ordinal WHEN 1 THEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.[value]) * 60 * 24
                                            WHEN 2 THEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.[value]) * 60
                                            WHEN 3 THEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SS.[value])
                            END) AS Minutes
                 FROM STRING_SPLIT(V.Duration,':',1) SS)D
WHERE D.[Minutes] < 80; --1 hour 20 minutes = 80 minutes;
```